# Replace word not being stored

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace, substr

I want to replace a keyword, Here is my algo

```
$replace="<span class=fb_term >".$term."</span>";
        $insmessage = str_ireplace($term, $replace, $post,$count)
```

The $count variable returns one.
but $insmessage doesn't have replaced word in it.If I store `"hello"` in `$replace` then it works fine,It seems like the HTML `"<span class=fb_term >"` is causing problem, Any help in this regard
Thanks

Comment: ot, your classname should be wrapped in double quotes

Comment: Just to be sure, have you applied some style to `.fb_term` to tell you it is there? Otherwise, it won't just show raw HTML in the browser!

Comment: @Martijn atleast PHP could consider it as a string and should add that

Comment: You sure your output didn't strip the html?
You tried directly outputting it (i.e. with var_dump)?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the raw html is stored in a variable right, there could be some way to show it in browser, may be print_r()?

Comment: If you replace it with another tag, i.e. `"<strong>".$term."</strong>"`, does that work? If so, work your way back to the span :)

Comment: @AndreschSerj that works, may be it will be showing the html

Comment: @Martijn Nope, [they don't need to be wrapped in double quotes](http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes).

Comment: You shall output with echo "<textarea style=\"width: 700px; height: 90px;\">"
  . $insmessage
  . "</textarea>"; to see HTML tags, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @jacouh Unless `$insmessage` happens to contain `</textarea>` :p

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, hope it does not... ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really, really hope I'm wrong here.

Let's say your input string is just `$post = $term;`. Nice and simple.

You said "if I store `"hello"` in `$replace` then it works fine". This suggests you tried the following:

```
$term = "derp";
$post = $term;
$replace = "hello";
$insmessage = str_ireplace($term,$replace,$post,$count);
echo $insmessage; // outputs hello
```

Now, this is where I hope I'm wrong, but bear with me. Seeing the above work, you then tried this.

```
$term = "derp";
$post = $term;
$replace = "<span class=fb_term >".$term."</span>";
$insmessge = str_ireplace($term,$replace,$post,$count);
echo $insmessage; // outputs derp... or does it?
```

In the browser, your HTML will be parsed. `<span>` has no special behaviour, and if you didn't supply any CSS for `.fb_term`, there's no visible sign of the span being there.

You tried `echo $count;` and saw 1. This means the replacement DID happen.

Try this for me:

```
echo "Original length: ".strlen($post)."<br />\n";
echo "New length: ".strlen($insmessage);
```

If I am right, you should see something like `4` for the original length, and `32` for the new length.

Please, please let me be wrong...

Comment: i really like how polite you are :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I would love to prove you wrong but you left no option for me

Answer (score 0):

I just extended your script with more data. And the replaced text is colored red, to make it easier to see.

```
$post       = "Some text. And HaLLO to all. Another HaLLO";
$term       = "hallo";
$replace    = "<span class='fb_term' style='color:red'>".$term."</span>";
$insmessage = str_ireplace($term, $replace, $post, $count);

echo $insmessage;
echo "<br />count ".$count;
```

In my case the $term is replaced, red colored and shows a count of 2. Maybe color the $replace text, to see if the count of 1 really happened.